# Beast Ball supply - am I cheesing it?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So I've just gotten to where

> Looker

gives me missions, and I noticed his dialogue says that I still have Beast Balls. Great. So I wondered what happens if I don't have any, so I put all of them on PC-stored Pokémon.

He gave me another. I repeated the process of hiding it. I got another.

Is there a limit to this? Or will there be a way to get more later on and I'm just being overly cheap hoarding them one by one now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can receive an unlimited number of extra Beast Balls, one at a time, from Looker. This is the only way to get extra Beast Balls in the post game.

The "limit" on the number you can physically have at the same time is the number of Pokemon that it is possible to store in your party and PC. Assuming 31 boxes of 30 Pokemon + 6 Battle Box + 6 for party + 1 extra, you've got a limit of 943 Beast Balls at once.

Comment: That seems like a hassle XD But fair enough. Is there an end to the quest once you've caught all of the Beasts? Or does the invasion of the UBs never end? (Also, 943 Balls and each one is worth "millions" according to Looker... Damn, he must be loaded XD)

Comment: The quest does end once you've caught all the Ultra Beasts, but you can still get Beast Balls from Looker.

Comment: Note that every time you finish a mission, Looker will give you 10 extra Beast Balls regardless of how many you still have.